# solution for wrong links via mod rewrite?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi and thanks for reading my question.
Its my first so please be gentle as im not a programmer but a barge captain, and curious ))

The situation:

I run a small website and we want to serve more languages, the website is based on Wordpress multisite.
After trying various translation solution we decided to go with transposh.

That plugin enables us to translate content easily and it becomes available at domain.com/en domain.com/fr etcetera those directory´s are virtual.

As we have different domain names for different languages i needed a solution to have the content of domain.com/en on domain2.com

What i did was to set the cache directory (static html) of domain.com as webroot of domain2.com. A fairly simple solution and it works like a charm.

The only problem i face is that the menu items link back to the domain.com and not domain2.com

I tried to make urls relative via wp core and two plugins but as the trailing /en or /fr is virtual making the urls relative just links back to domain.com

I have spend two days googling and im realy out of ideas. I tried different php script for search and replace, cgi scripts, perl scripts but none seem to do the job. I dont have shell access.

I was wondering if its posible to do smth like that with mod rewrite and if posible then how?

simply put:

static html site with wrong links
can i change the links via htaccess or other method which is easy (relatively) to understand and maintain?

The cache gets rebuild now and then of course

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question to highlight the problem better, it's a bit of a wall of text right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by an other approach:

Instead of using the cache i creatd a cronjob with wget:

/usr/bin/wget -np -P /destination-eg-yourwebroot/ --html-extension -nH -p -k -r http://domain.com

This creates a html copy of your website in the webroot of the new domain
For some reason wget does not always update the links in the copy, so they will point to original domain

We can run the command again but then prepend it with /usr/bin/wget -nc -k

/usr/bin/wget -nc -k -np -P /destination-eg-yourwebroot/ --html-extension -nH -p -k -r http://domain.com

It will update the links correctly, including css urls

U now have a clean copy of your website on a different domain